# Ionic Test on Multiple Devices

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I was wondering if there is a way to serve an ionic app to multiple devices without having to post it to the app store?
is the only way ionic devapp and do all the devices have to be on the same network in order for it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to test your application on multiply iOS devices (without having to post it to the app store) you can do it in few ways:

1. Install application on every device with Xcode by cable connection :)
2. With normal Apple Developer account, and Ad Hoc distribution (You have to register iOS devices uuids in your Apple Developer account and create special html page with link to your ipa file) [more info](https://support.magplus.com/hc/en-us/articles/204270188-iOS-Creating-an-Ad-Hoc-Distribution-Provisioning-Profile)
3. With enteprise Apple Developer account (same html page with link, but no device registration needed) [more info](https://www.goodbarber.com/blog/distribute-your-ios-app-out-of-the-store-with-the-apple-developer-enterprise-program-a871/)

Comment: When you say normal developer account do you mean the one that costs $100/year?